# Can an onbeforeunload event complete "too slowly"? What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, pubnub

This seems to be a common kind of complaint, but I don't see any exact duplicates and more importantly I don't see any working **answers**, so I'm joining the crowd.

I have some code that does

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { PubNub.publish(...); };
```

to publish a message to a [PubNub channel](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html) when the user leaves the current page. It's a chat forum, and we want to publish the fact that User X is no longer in the room. (Please suppress the urge to suggest other designs, such as having every user send a heartbeat; this is just a toy project I'm playing with.)

Watching the channel in another browser tab, I observe that the PubNub message gets published successfully 100% of the time when I

- close the tab

and occasionally (both yes and no) when I

- refresh by clicking the circley icon in the address bar

but apparently never when I

- navigate away by clicking a link
- navigate away by entering a new URL in the address bar
- refresh by entering the same URL in the address bar
- refresh by hitting `⌘R`

Notice that even putting `return "please don't exit";` in my onbeforeunload handler results in flaky publishing: sometimes I enter the same URL in the address bar and the publish happens, sometimes I enter the same URL and the publish doesn't happen.

Is this some quirk of Safari, and if so is there a known workaround?
Alternatively, is PubNub.publish() somehow "too slow" or "too multithreaded" to succeed during an onbeforeunload event? I don't really understand how onbeforeunload works.

(For the time being, the whole code can be accessed [here](http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/~ajo/disseminate/ping.html), but if you're reading this question a month from now, be aware that that link may be dead and/or fixed.)

Comment: Also try `PUBNUB.bind('unload,beforeunload'...` trying both **`unload`** and **`beforeunload`** events - an example found here - https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/blob/gh-pages/js/webrtc.js#L282

Comment: @PubNub FYI, the `bind` method doesn't have an entry on the "Javascript API Reference" page [here](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html). What does it actually do behind the scenes that's different from what I tried to do?

Comment: The `bind` method uses the browser vendor event registration methods similar to that of `jQuery` and `AngularJS`.

Answer (score 0):

This is really what our Presence feature is for. Check it out here:

http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/overview/presence.html

This way, when you "leave" the channel, the Presence system can broadcast this to those interested. Is this what you are looking for?

geremy

Comment: That's definitely how I *should* be doing it in practice, but it doesn't technically answer the question of why my handwritten Javascript doesn't work.